# Detect URL in txt

Tags: javascript, node.js

*I have txt file with urls. How to take this url's separate to use them in js code? I was trying do it with .split(/\n\t/g)*

```
   let sites = await readFile('./sites.txt');
    sites = sites.split(/\n\t/g);

    await context.overridePermissions(sites, ['notifications']);
    try {
        await context.overridePermissions(sites, ['push']);
    } catch (e) {}
```

Comment: The answer will depend greatly on the format of the document itself.  Can you give us a snippet of what the file looks like?

Comment: If you're using node.js, you're probably looking for the `readFile` function in the `fs` module. Unless you've defined it elsewhere, `readFile` is not a native function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things you should be aware of:

1. NodeJS `fs.readFile` does not work with `await` / promises out of the box
2. `fs.readFile` gives you a `Buffer`, not a string unless encoding is specified (eg. 'utf8'):

```
fs.readFile('./sites.txt', 'utf8', callback);
```

3. If your file consists only URLs (one url per a line) you can split by a new line sign (like `\n`), but you must keep in mind that different platforms save new lines in text files differently - on Unix it's just `\n`, on Windows: `\r\n`.

So your code may look like:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./sites.txt', 'utf8', (err, content) => { 
  if (err) {
    console.error(err); 
    return;
  } 
  const urls = content.split('\n');
  // do sth with urls
});
```

If you want to use await or promise pattern you can for example promisify `fs.readFile`:

```
const util = require('util');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
```

Then in your async function:

```
async function getURLs() {
  const content = await readFile('./sites.txt', 'utf8');
  return content.split('\n');
}
```

Comment: i have all these requiers, async func etc.
i need to find in .txt file (https ://xxx .com https ://ccc.com https ://vvv .com) url and use it in my code below: 
`await page.goto("my url here", {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2"
    });`

Comment: function `getURLs()` from my example should return you an array of urls

Comment: Does your './sites.txt' consists only URLs - one per line ?

Comment: Can you add some content of './sites.txt' to your original question ?